# Android Studio Canary versions (Arctic Fox and Bumblebee) are not allowing Imported Modules feature to work

Tags: android, android-studio

When using Android Studio Arctic Fox or Bumblebee, when we try to do "File -> New -> Import Module" and try to add Gradle project. The "Finish or Next" buttons are greyed out.

If you repeat the exact same process on Stable version 4.1 for example, the Import Module feature works.

Is this a known issue or is there a workaround to import modules for canary versions?

Comment: Temporary workaround here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68738929/5773037

Answer (score 2):

Existing module can be imported manually:

1. Move existing module folder to project folder
2. In settings.gradle file add include part for your existing module:

   include ':app', **':your-module'**
3. Go to app's gradle file and add dependency to it:

   **implementation project(":your-module")**
4. Sync gradle

Now your module should be successfully imported

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks for suggestions! I've updated the answer to this question. Now it gives some suggestions for overcoming the issue

Comment: I think you are answsering  the "workaround" part of the question. Good. Just for being more obvious you might want to start your post by saying so.