# Can't import module in Android Studio Arctic Fox

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

Next/Finish button does not become enabled even after selecting the right module path. It does not show any error. Android studio version is 2020.3.1 (Latest as of 3 August, 2021).[image]

Comment: Same problem for me

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### [ Fixed ] in Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1)

This issue was fixed in Android Studio Bumblebee. Please Update Android Studio to Bumblebee or Latest Version

---

##### This Bug is in Android studio Arctic Fox,

Many people are posted this issue on `issuetracker` but nobody get solution from `Android studio` team side.
here is some links of that issues posted on `issuetracker`.
[Link 1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195336461) ,
[Link 2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195849585) ,
[Link 3](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195598564) ,
[Link 4](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196100679) ,
[Link 5](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195318441) ,
[Link 6](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191209456) ,
[Link 7](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195340090)

#### *So here is Temporary Workaround*

- copy `your-module` folder in your project directory
- Add below line in `settings.gradle`

  ```
  include ':your-module' // your-module is module name
  ```
- click `sync now`
- Done

Comment: Thanks, was not expecting to face such issues in Android Studio update.

Comment: It's October now, is there any update fix this problem now?

Comment: @shingo Still not Solved.. :-( , Open Link1 in answer and star it , it may lead to solve this issue

Comment: Also add this to your app module's `build.gradle` file under dependencies:

`implementation project(path: ':your-module')`

Answer (score 5):

First

1- copy your-module folder in your project directory

2- Add this in settings.gradle (include ':your-module')

3- Click Sync

4- Finish

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading to Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4 did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

**My version of the Workaround**

1. Add a new folder "*lib*" (or whatever name) inside the project path
2. Add (aar /jar) to the new folder called "*lib*"
3. Add the path of the module to app's build.gradle (apps)

> ```
> dependencies {
>
>       implementation project(path: ':lib')
>
>       implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
>    }
> ```

4. Add the "build.gradle" to the "new folder" (just create the file if you don't have one)

This how my build.gradle look inside

```
  configurations.maybeCreate("default")
  artifacts.add("default", file('yourArrOrJar.aar'))
```

5. include "lib" in settings.gradle

> ```
> include ':app',':lib'
> ```

Comment: Thank you man, saved my time. Thanks a lot. I just added "implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')" and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have fund out that it is a bug. Many people are facing the problem using version 2020.3.1. Version 4.2.2 is working well in this case.
Here are some links about this bug:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195340090 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191209456
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195318441
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195336461

Answer (score 1):

Latest Android Studio Patch Fixes this Bug. Make sure you update to Security Patch 4 or above.

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/12/android-studio-arctic-fox-202031-patch.html

Initial Issue : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191209456?pli=1

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved in

**Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4 (December 2021)**

Also mentioned in [Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#arctic-fox)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using Android Studio Chipmunk resolves the issue but it might not be the case for the rest of y'all

Answer (score 0):

```
Let me Make it Simple for all of you facing this problem.. Try doing it manually.

In Android Studio

1- File -> New  -> New Module -> Select Android Library -> Rename the Module with your Module Name -> Finish

2- After Build Finished, Open your Project Folder 
-> Open the new Module Folder you just created 
-> Open Src Folder 
-> Delete the Main Folder
-> Copy the Main Folder of Your Module.. (Replace it with your Main Folder)

3- Don't Forget to Open And Copy the Build.gradle File Of Your Module (if Needed) 
as it Contains the Dependencies for it to Work.. 

4- Sync And Build

5- Finish
```