# How to import an existing module into the newest version of android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have imported a module before but all of a sudden after updating to the Arctic Fox version, the "Finish" button is now greyed out.
[image: Import Module window showing the greyed out "Finish" button]

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think android studio is not able to recognize your files as a module. Is it a valid module? Could you try `Invalidate Caches & Restart`?

Comment: I already tried that.

Comment: Also, I have another project on my PC that has imported that module

Comment: Can you put a static module name instead of `:common`?

Comment: Just tried that. didn't work

Comment: I just found out that it's a bug in the newest version of android studio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68636809/cant-import-module-in-android-studio-arctic-fox

I'll try the fix in that link. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't import module in Android Studio Arctic Fox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68636809/cant-import-module-in-android-studio-arctic-fox)